# How to read escape characters as text in Java?

Tags: java, android

```
public List<String> readRSS(String feedUrl, String openTag, String closeTag)
            throws IOException, MalformedURLException {

        URL url = new URL(feedUrl);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String currentLine;
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Integer tagEndIndex = 0;
            Integer tagStartIndex = 0;
            while (tagStartIndex >= 0) {
                tagStartIndex = currentLine.indexOf(openTag, tagEndIndex);
                if (tagStartIndex >= 0) {
                    tagEndIndex = currentLine.indexOf(closeTag, tagStartIndex);
                    tempList.add(currentLine.substring(tagStartIndex + openTag.length(), tagEndIndex) + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        if (tempList.size() > 0) {
            if(openTag.contains("title")){
                tempList.remove(0);
                tempList.remove(0);
            }
            else if(openTag.contains("desc")){
                tempList.remove(0);
            }
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

I wrote this code to read an RSS feed. It all works fine but when the parser finds a char like this `&#xD;` it breaks. This is because it can't find its ending tags becuase the xml is escaped.

I don't know how I can fix it inside my code. Could anyone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: So you want to read the escape characters as text and then (maybe) skip them, right?

Comment: @progyammer Yes i want to skip them. What now happens is the following: RSS reader see a &#xD; and then quites reading so it never reaches the </title> tag and crashes. Updated the OP with image so it's more clear

Comment: Yep. It's a parser so it does what it's supposed to do when it encounters as escape sequence. You need to somehow override that rule and read everything as text; your post processing of the input is only going to increase a bit.

Comment: @progyammer I understand the issue :). Anyways do you have an idea how I can achieve a fix

Comment: Umm....nope. I have just edited the question title to attract appropriate people to this post.

Comment: can you post a sample RSS feed xml? The `&#xD;` is a line break character so does that mean that the `<title>` and `</title>` tags are on separate lines when you read it? Or are both tags on the same line and the special character somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @tima Here you go http://www.ad.nl/home/rss.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the special character `&#xD;` is a line break so your start and end tags wind up on different lines. So, if you are reading line by line it will not work with the code that you have.

You can try something like this:

```
StringBuffer fullLine = new StringBuffer();

while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    int tagStartIndex = currentLine.indexOf(openTag, 0);
    int tagEndIndex = currentLine.indexOf(closeTag, tagStartIndex);

    // both tags on the same line
    if (tagStartIndex != -1 && tagEndIndex != -1) {
        // process the whole line
        tempList.add(currentLine);
        fullLine = new StringBuffer();
    // no tags on this line but the buffer has been started
    } else if (tagStartIndex == -1 && tagEndIndex == -1 && fullLine.length() > 0) {
        /*
         * add the current line to the buffer; it is part 
         * of a larger line
         */
        fullLine.append(currentLine);
    // start tag is on this line
    } else if (tagStartIndex != -1 && tagEndIndex == -1) {
        /*
         *  line started but did not have an end tag; add it to 
         *  a new buffer
         */
        fullLine = new StringBuffer(currentLine);
        // end tag is on this line
    } else if (tagEndIndex != -1 && tagStartIndex == -1) {
        /*
         *  line ended but did not have a start tag; add it to 
         *  the current buffer and then process the buffer
         */
        fullLine.append(currentLine);
        tempList.add(fullLine.toString());
        fullLine = new StringBuffer();
    }
}
```

Given this sample input:

```
<title>another &#xD;
title 0</title>
<title>another title 1</title>
<title>another title 2</title>
<title>another title 3</title>
<desc>description 0</desc>
<desc>another &#xD;
description 1</desc>
<title>another title 4</title>
<title>another &#xD;
another line in between &#xD;
title 5</title>
```

The full lines in the `tempList` for `title` become:

```
<title>another &#xD;title 0</title>
<title>another title 1</title>
<title>another title 2</title>
<title>another title 3</title>
<title>another title 4</title>
<title>another &#xD;another line in between &#xD;title 5</title>
```

And for `desc`:

```
<desc>description 0</desc>
<desc>another &#xD;description 1</desc>
```

You should test this approach for performance on your full RSS feed. And also note that the special characters will not be escaped.